# Information Dialog Box when selecting input fields

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched, but cannot find the answer to this question.  I think I just do not know the proper name for what I am trying to achieve.

Basically, I want to setup some input fields as if we are creating an account at a website.  However, I would like a dialog box to pop up to the right of the input field when the user clicks inside of the input field.  This dialog box pop up would provide further information of what exactly needs to go inside the input field to guide the user.  I would like the dialog box to not be interactive so it does not get in the way.

I am sure there is some tutorial out there for this.  However, I am guessing I just do not know the correct name for this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you mean a **tooltip dialog** type of functionality provided by Dojo. This **[link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/TooltipDialog.html)** should provide you with some explanation and examples. The examples show on a button but can be easily done on `input` field also.

I am pretty sure this would be present in other technologies also like jQuery.